# Get number of documents in collection firestore

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to count how many documents a collection in Firestore has, using python?

I just found this code

```
    functions.firestore.document('collection/{documentUid}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

    if (!change.before.exists) {
        // New document Created : add one to count

        db.doc(docRef).update({numberOfDocs: FieldValue.increment(1)});
    
    } else if (change.before.exists && change.after.exists) {
        // Updating existing document : Do nothing

    } else if (!change.after.exists) {
        // Deleting document : subtract one from count

        db.doc(docRef).update({numberOfDocs: FieldValue.increment(-1)});

    }

return;
});
```

How I can do this with python?

Comment: I would not go that way. You would have to move into the gcp world instead of staying within the Firebase world, which is much more convenient.  Firebase functions are implemented using Javascript or Typescript, and it is quite easy to do for a Python developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore (like many NoSQL databases) has no built in aggregation queries. If you want to determine the number of documents, you have two main options:

1. Read all documents, and then count them in the client.
2. Keep the document count in the database itself, and then update it with every add/delete operation.

While the firsts option is simpler, it is less scalable as you'll end up with clients reading all documents just to determine the count. That's why you'll find most questions/articles about counting documents focusing on the second approach.

For more on this, see:

- The Firestore documentation on [aggregation queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation).
- The Firestore documentation on [distributed counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters), which you'll need to consider if your count changes more frequently than about once per second.

Answer (score 9):

### New in February 2023

Firestore now [has added](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/python#version_610_-_02_february_2023) the `count()` method to queries and collections in the Python SDK.

**Usage**

The documentation does not say much about it at the moment, but here is how I manage to use it.

You need `firebase-admin` in 6.1.0 or later.

```
from firebase_admin import firestore

# Do the credentials stuff if necessary
db = firestore.client()

# Count all docs in collection
my_collection = db.collection("foo")
count_query = my_collection.count()
query_result = count_query.get()
print("Nb docs in collection:", query_result[0][0].value)

# Count some docs via a query
any_query = db.collection("foo").where("myField", "==", 0)
count_query = simple_query.count()
query_result = count_query.get()
print("Nb docs in query:", query_result[0][0].value)
```